# Add a node without content to a tree in forest

Tags: trees, forest

I switched to `forest` and now I wonder how to draw the following picture:
[image]

I have the code below, but I cannot find out how to get the connection to `dass` right. I tried phantom nodes but then the lines are not drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[{V3[+{\sc fin},+{\sc mc}]}
  [{N2[acc,+{\sc top}]} [wen\\who] ]
  [{V3[+{\sc mc}]/N2[acc]}
    [{V[9,+{\sc mc}]} [glaubt\\believes] ]
    [{N2[nom]} [du\\you] ] 
    [{V3[+dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]} 
      [dass\\that]
      [{V3[$-$dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]} 
         [{N2[nom]} [ich\\I] ]
         [{V[6,$-${\sc mc}]} [gesehen habe\\seen have,triangle] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an empty node and change the shape for empty nodes to `coordinate` using

```
empty nodes/.style={
  delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}}
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}},
empty nodes/.style={
  delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges,empty nodes
[{V3[+{\sc fin},+{\sc mc}]}
  [{N2[acc,+{\sc top}]} [wen\\who] ]
  [{V3[+{\sc mc}]/N2[acc]}
    [{V[9,+{\sc mc}]} [glaubt\\believes] ]
    [{N2[nom]} [du\\you] ] 
    [{V3[+dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]} 
      [{}[dass\\that] ]
      [{V3[$-$dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]} 
         [{N2[nom]} [ich\\I] ]
         [{V[6,$-${\sc mc}]} [gesehen habe\\seen have,triangle] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses your idea with a phantom node and the `name` argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[{V3[+{\sc fin},+{\sc mc}]}
  [{N2[acc,+{\sc top}]} [wen\\who] ]
  [{V3[+{\sc mc}]/N2[acc]}
    [{V[9,+{\sc mc}]} [glaubt\\believes] ]
    [{N2[nom]} [du\\you] ] 
    [{V3[+dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]},name=A 
      [,phantom [ dass\\that,name=B,edge={}]]
      [{V3[$-$dass,$-${\sc mc}]/N2[acc]}
         [{N2[nom]} [ich\\I] ]
         [{V[6,$-${\sc mc}]} [gesehen habe\\seen have,triangle] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw  (B) --+(0,2.5)--(A);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks. But can you explain how that works? Why does it help to connect A and B? The phantom does not seem to play a role here?

Comment: Ah, OK. I got it. Tried it myself. Without the phantom it keeps drawing the line. Phantom avoids this and then we can draw it by hand. Thanks!

Comment: the `edge={}` is not valid without the phantom node. At least for me :-)

Comment: @Herbert: `edge={}` by itself does nothing, as the argument of `edge` is a keylist and keylists behave additively by default (section 3.3 of the manual). Use `edge'={}` to get rid of your edges ;-)